# How to properly parse Devanagari / Hindi for @font-face

Tags: css, cordova, unicode, fonts, font-face

Starting with this string :

```
वृत्तयः पञ्चतय्यः क्लिष्टाक्लिष्टा
```

I'm trying to render it on my mobile device ( via Cordova / PhoneGap ).

On my browser ( `localhost:8000` ), it shows up fine. Just as it shows up fine in the example. But on my device, it looks like this :

[image]

It is definitely adopting my font ( Karma-Light ) because I notice the aliasing is finer than the default Helvetica, sans-serif, etc.

My CSS looks like this :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Karma';
    src: local('Karma'), url('../fonts/Karma-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    unicode-range: U+0900–097F;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.devanagari { font-family: 'Karma', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
```

I've tried a variety of different unicode-ranges, as well as omitting a unicode-range but everything manifests in the same manner.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone gets stuck here!

Open up your `index.html` in your `/src/`

And make sure it says this!

```
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
```

Declaring the charset makes it work.